# how can I loop with an error message?

Tags: bash, shell

**Latest Version**

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
shopt -s nocasematch

#vars
redbgbold='\e[1;97;41m'
resetcolor='\e[0m'
RegExFQDN='(?=^.{4,253}$)(^((?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-)\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,63}$)'

#functions
ask() {
  local input
  until
    read -rp "$1 > " input >&2 || return 1
    grep -q -P "$2" <<< "$input"
  do
    printf "ERROR - "${redbgbold}"\"$input\""${resetcolor}" is not a valid " >&2; sed "s/.*the //" <<< "$1" >&2
  done
  printf '%s\n' "$input"
}

#code    
while [ -z $fqdn ]; do
  fqdn=$(ask "Enter the FQDN" $RegExFQDN)
  echo "FQDN is $fqdn"
done
```

**The Question**

I have a read line, and I want to take what the user entered and see if it matches my regex, if it matches we leave the loop, if it fails it prints an error and we do the loop again until we get a match.  It looks redundant to me, and I assume there should be a better way but not sure what that should be.

**Original Code**

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e    
shopt -s nocasematch

function RegexValidation() {
  if [ "$2" = "fqdn" ]; then
    if [ `echo $1 | grep -c -P '(?=^.{1,254}$)(^(?>(?!\d+\.)[a-z0-9_\-]{1,63}\.?)+(?:[a-z]{2,})$)'` == "0" ]; then
      echo "ERROR - $1 is not a valid FQDN"
      unset $!{1}
    fi
  fi
}

while [ -z $fqdn ]; do
  read -e -r -p "Enter the Fully Qualified Domain Name > " fqdn
  RegexValidation $fqdn fqdn
done
shopt -u nocasematch
```

any help is appreciated.

**Update #1** - fixed formatting issues.
**Update #2** - using [that other guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1899640/)'s suggestions with a few additional tweaks

Comment: Is that final `shopt -u nocasematch` meant to be part of the script? If so, it should be indented. But it's unnecessary, since `shopt` affects only the current shell process, and the shell running the script is just about to terminate at that point.

Comment: Yeah, it was, fixed it.  There is more code, but i took out the other parts, it was residual to that.

Comment: As an aside, ```[ `...` == "foo" ]``` has a few issues. Not quoting the backticks means that the result from your `echo | grep` pipeline can be split into any number of words (not guaranteed to be exactly 1, as the `[` command requires). And `==` isn't guaranteed to be a supported string comparison operator at all (the POSIX sh standard only specifies `=`).

Comment: Also, `function` is nonportable -- consider using the standardized function declaration syntax, which is just `RegexValidation() {`, with no `function` preceding. Many bashisms add value to compensate for the reduction in portability, but that one in particular has no compensating benefit.

Comment: Consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing what it finds.

Comment: (I'd also suggest switching your regex from PCRE to ERE, and using `[[ $2 =~ $regex ]]`, which is built-in functionality in ksh and bash, rather than relying on `grep -P` -- which is a platform-specific extension).

Comment: (Also, `grep ... <<<"$1"` or even `printf '%s\n' "$1" | grep ...` will be more reliable than `echo "$1" | grep ...` -- see [the POSIX spec for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html), particularly the APPLICATION USAGE section, to appreciate just how unpredictable behavior of `echo` can be).

Comment: I would use ERE but not sure how to do the regex for that to quantify a valid FQDN.  The best i could come find was `([a-z0-9][-a-z0-9\.]{0,61}[a-z0-9]\.[a-z]{2,5})` but its not as good as the PCRE regex that I have posted above

Answer (score 1):

Have the function return a status, which you can test with `if` in the loop.

And rather than use `test` to check the result of `grep`, just test it directly with `if`. `grep` returns a non-zero status if the input doesn't match.

```
function RegexValidation() {
  if [ "$2" = "fqdn" ]; then
    if ! echo "$1" | grep -q -P '(?=^.{1,254}$)(^(?>(?!\d+\.)[a-z0-9_\-]{1,63}\.?)+(?:[a-z]{2,})$)'; then
      echo "ERROR - $1 is not a valid FQDN"
      return 1
    fi
    return 0
  fi
}

while :; do
  read -e -r -p "Enter the Fully Qualified Domain Name > " fqdn
  if RegexValidation "$fqdn" fqdn
  then break
  fi
done
```

Also, remember to quote your variables.

Comment: Speaking of "remember to quote", the command substitution whose output is being compared by `test` isn't quoted here. (Given that that command substitution contains backslashes, changing from backticks to `$()` is probably also called for).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The command substitution is a `grep -c` command. It just returns a single number, no backslashes.

Comment: ...and if it fails with an error (say, because it's run somewhere `grep -P` isn't available) and returns nothing on stdout?

Comment: As for the backslashes, I wasn't referring to backslashes in the returned content, but backslashes in the source. Their modified semantics inside backticks is one more thing to keep track of in reading code -- best to switch to modern command substitution syntax and moot that need.

Comment: I just got rid of the use of `test`.

Answer (score 1):

I would do basically the same thing, but split it differently to make it easier to reuse:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

ask() {
  local input
  until
    read -rp "$1 > " input >&2 || return 1
    grep -q -P "$2" <<< "$input"
  do
    echo "Invalid answer. Try again" >&2
  done
  printf '%s\n' "$input"
}

ask_fqdn() {
  ask "$1" '(?=^.{1,254}$)(^(?>(?!\d+\.)[a-z0-9_\-]{1,63}\.?)+(?:[a-z]{2,})$)'
}


fqdn=$(ask_fqdn "Enter first FQDN")
echo "You wrote $fqdn"

fqdn=$(ask_fqdn "Enter second FQDN")
echo "This time it was $fqdn"

number=$(ask "And now a number because why not" '^\d+$')
echo "So $number"
```

Now you don't have to write a new loop every time you want new information, and you can easily ask for new things without modifying the existing functions.